# Error in bash if statement: Conditional binary operator expected

Tags: bash, grep

I have an if statement in my bash script as follows:

```
if [[ eb status my-env-staging-worker | grep 'Green' -ne 0 ] || [ eb status my-env-staging-web | grep 'Green' -ne 0 ]]
```

Basically if the first or second eb status command dont have the string Green I'd like to execute some other stuff.

However I get the following Error:

Conditional binary operator expected
syntax error near status
script returned exit code 2

Could you tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[[` and `[` are not for grouping. They're independent commands. Instead of `if [[ cmd1 -ne 0 ] || [ cmd2 -ne 0 ]]`, leave out the brackets and the tests and simply write `if cmd1 || cmd2`.

```
if eb status my-env-staging-worker | grep -q 'Green' || eb status my-env-staging-web | grep -q 'Green'
```

I've added `-q` to suppress grep's output since you only care about the return code.

If you want to invert the condition, write:

```
if ! eb status my-env-staging-worker | grep -q 'Green' && ! eb status my-env-staging-web | grep -q 'Green'
```

or

```
if ! { eb status my-env-staging-worker | grep -q 'Green' || eb status my-env-staging-web | grep -q 'Green'; }
```

Here you can see `{` and `}` used for grouping. Curly braces and parentheses are bash's grouping tokens.

Comment: Seems like the OP wants the opposite, so some `!` are needed.

Comment: I guess _the opposite_ was ambiguous, but I think it should be `! cmd1 || ! cmd2`.

Comment: Yeah, it's ambiguous. OP can make the proper adjustment if I interpreted the question wrong.